Calling a Console App from Blazor Server web app with parameters
I have a Blazor Server app, that when a user clicks a button, it will cycle through a List , generate a pdf document and email the users in the list (over 350 pdfs and users, over 10 minutes to run).
I built a Console app to be called from the web app OnClick method, but have discovered I cant seem to pass parameters to the Console App (List<T>, and a couple of strings).
The console app complains on build that it does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point. It does have Main method, but with a parameter list:
static void Main(List<CCStmt_Trans> stmtData, string moYr)

What is a better strategy to accomplish this?

"It does have Main method, but with a parameter list" - Which is not a suitable main method.  The main method for an application accepts an array of strings representing the command-line arguments, nothing else.  How are you trying to invoke this console application in your web application?

Why not just pass the task to a service running on the threadpool or background task?

I'll look to create an external service for this. Not alot of cases have come up for me like this in the past.
Thanks everyone.
